# Index error on Polynomial array program

Tags: python, list

I have this code that receivestwo lists (assumed to be in power order) that I'm trying to multiply. However, I keep getting an index error and I don't understand why.

```
def multiply(a, b):
a.reverse()
b.reverse()
c=[]
al = len(a)
bl = len(b)

for i in range (al):
    for j in range (bl):
        k = a[i]*b[j]
        ii=i+j
        c[ii]+=k

c.reverse()

return (c)
```

Comment: `range(*)` ==> `range(len(*))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    c[ii]+=k
```

This line will cause an error because c[ii] goes past the end of the list.

You can't increase the size of a list by assigning to indices that are out of range; you have to use a mutating method such as `append` or `extend`, or just create the list with its elements already present.

```
c = [0 for _ in range(len(a) + len(b))]
```

Comment: So an empty list isnt boundless... Good to know.

Comment: So I used the elements already present method... but Im curious to see how you would use append or extend here.